# Dynamically load multiple JsTrees using Ajax

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'd like to perform a simple search that returns an array of JSON data objects that turn into jsTrees.

I've stripped down and removed parts of the code that I didn't find relavent to the question (themes, formatting, etc).

**HTML Page:**

```
Results:

<div id="results"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getJsonData", 
    dataType: "json",
}).done(function( data ) {

    var newData;

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {

        newData += '<div id="tree' + index + '"></div>';

        $('#tree' + index).jstree({
            "json_data" : v,
            "plugins" : \[ "themes", "json_data" \]
        });
    }

    $('#results').html(newData);

}
```

A typical search would yield something like the following that the user could interact with:

### [image: Results page]